# How do I update a csv file when a cell has been updated in QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a QTableWidget with several rows.  When the user edits a cell, I want the data they edited to automatically be updated in a csv file.  I know how to update the csv file, but I can't figure out how to recognize when the data has been edited and pull it out of the cell. How do I recognize when the data has changed?

[image: GUI]

**UPDATE:** @Gluttton - I am using the QTableWidget inside of a main window & I create the items using a for loop (see both below).  I overwrite the item when I create the table.  How can I reference the item if I don't keep it?

#### Main Class

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->updateDataSummary();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

....

for (int x = 0; x < rowOfData.size(); x++)
{
    rowData = rowOfData.at(x).split(",");
    if((ui->table_Data->rowCount() - x) == 0) ui->table_Data->insertRow(x);
    for (int y = 0; y < rowData.size(); y++)
    {
        QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(rowData[y],QTableWidgetItem::Type);
        if( y < 43 ) item->setFlags(item->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable);
        ui->table_Data->setItem(x,y,item);
        ui->table_Data->repaint();
    }
}
```

@Glutton - Thank you for your help!  I made two modifications to the code you showed below.  You can see the changes I made in the code below.

```
connect (ui->table_Data, SIGNAL ( itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *) ), this, SLOT ( onItemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *) ) );

....

void MainWindow::onItemChanged( QTableWidgetItem * item)
{
    // Where?
    int column = item->column ();
    int row    = item->row ();
    qDebug () << "Data in item [" << column << "] ["<< row << "was changed.";
}
```

Comment: Based your Update. You don't need deal with `item`, you need subscribe some slot (see below) on your `table_data` (look at my example `connection`). Can you see? You need connect `table_data` with `MainWindow`. `table_data` "say" you what `item` was changed.

Comment: I've renamed variables in example according to your code.

Comment: So I should have something like:  protected slots: void on_table_data_change & then connect( signal(table_data_changed...?

Comment: All right: you need create `slot` and connect it. You can try first with debug output (I've updated my example - see debug output inside `onItemChanged`).

Comment: Your modifications are right (also you need declare `onItemChanged` as `slot`). So is it work as expected or you have any trouble?

Comment: I did not have any trouble.  I declared onItemChanged as a slot in my header, but not in my main class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should subscribe on signal:

[`void QTableWidget::itemChanged ( QTableWidgetItem * item )`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged)

through `item`you can access to `data`, `row` and `column`:

```
// In header file.
class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow (QWidget *  parent = NULL);
    QTableWidget * table_data;
...
protected slots:
    void onItemChanged ( QTableWidgetItem *);
...
};

// In source file.
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow (QWidget *  parent)
{
table_data = new QTableWidget (this);
connect (table_data, SIGNAL (itemChanged ( QTableWidgetItem *) ), this, slot (onItemChanged ( QTableWidgetItem *) ) );
}


void MainWindow::onItemChanged ( QTableWidgetItem * item)
{
    // Where?
    int column = item->column ();
    int row    = item->row ();
    // What?
    QVariant   = item->data ();
    qDebug () << "Data in item [" << column << "] ["<< row << "] was changed.";
}
```

Comment: Either this or switch to a proper model and `QTableView`.

Comment: @peppe, yes. For `QTableView` the approach will be similar (instead of `QTableWidgetItem *` will be `QStandardItemModelItem *`). Isn't it?

Comment: Depends if you're using a `QStandardItemModel` for holding your data. You could just implement a custom model wrapping the CSV file.